# Does AMP Project support Google One-tap?

Tags: amp-html, google-identity

I'm looking at AMP for sign up, landing, static and blog pages. On each of these pages we plan to allow users to sign up/in using [Google One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/). I'd like to know if it is possible to call Google One Tap on AMP pages.

Answer (score 2):

That's currently not supported. I'd suggest [filing a feature request on Github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

Amp Project is starting to support now

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/extensions/amp-onetap-google

### Overview

You can use the amp-onetap-google component to embed a Google One Tap on the page, to allow users to sign into your websites with Google accounts.

Example

```
<amp-onetap-google
  layout="nodisplay"
  data-src="https://rp.com/intermediate"
></amp-onetap-google>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, One tap on AMP pages are supported by Frame method. the complete google official document is avaialble @

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe